# Error: CONNECTION INTERRUPTED in Xcode running on Device

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, delegates, objective-c-blocks

Could someone please explain what this error means?

```
CONNECTION INTERRUPTED
```

I'm writing files to storage from a method I'm calling from a block. I also sometimes get this message before the "CONNECTION INTERRUPTED":

```
__47+[TIUserDictionaryController loadWordKeyPairs:]_block_invoke_0  Received nil NSData for TIRemoteDataUserDict
```

I call this method (the one that writes) at my app did finish launching method and it works, but for some reason it won't work when called within the block. I've tried not using the block and instead a delegate but I still get this error/crash. This error has been completely inconsistent.

I've never seen any error like this before, so I don't know what more information to give. If you have questions please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this would work.
But appDidFinsihLaunching should return as early as possible. Since if the method does not return in a specified timeframe, the watchdog would terminate the application.

So I would suggest to call this method using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method with a delay of about 1 sec or whatever suits you.

Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Can you send me a project showing your issue? I will try to solve it and send back the solved one.

Comment: I am unable to download. Cannot open page browser says. Can you please upload to some file hosting service like rghost.net

Comment: It should work, it's a dropbox link. Try using a different browser or something. If it still doesn't work, give me your email and I'll just email it to you.

Comment: At what time does the error comes? I run it and it successfully opened the main menu. Any specific steps to reproduce the error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21629/discussion-between-manox-and-akshay-shah)

Answer (score 10):

I got this 'error' as well, it appeared to be the case that I simply used to much memory on the device before the system could tell me this. I was trying to show many very big images on the screen at start up. I solved it by either removing the some of the images or making their memory consumption smaller.

EDIT: I know it is marked as solved, but I had the same problem, without the answer solving my case, I then figured to write my solution and hope it helps someone, as I know that I would have appreciated this answer.